# EF7 beta6: ReadAsync error on Update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating an API using ASP.NET5 and Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta 6, and when I try to execute an update, I get this Exception:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateException' ocurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details."}
>
> Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed.

The update operation finish correctly, and the changes are persisted to the database, but I get this exception.

My code is really simple, and I do not try to read anything after the update operation:

```
public class CompanyRepository : ICompanyRepository
{

    MrBellhopContext _dbcontext;


    public async Task UpdateAsync(Company company)
    {
        _dbcontext.Update(company);
        await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}



[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CompanyController : Controller
{


    [HttpPut]
    public async void UpdateAsync([FromBody] Company company)
    {
        if ((!ModelState.IsValid) || (company == null))
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await _repository.UpdateAsync(company);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the Stacktrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.<ConsumeAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MrBellhop.Data.Repositories.Company.CompanyRepository.<UpdateAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\SciOf\MrBellhop\MrBellhop.Data\Repositories\Company\CompanyRepository.cs:line 47
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MrBellhop.API.Controllers.Company.CompanyController.<UpdateAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\SciOf\MrBellhop\MrBellhop.API\Controllers\Company\CompanyController.cs:line 62
```

**Does anyone know how to solve this issue?**

Comment: File a bug report with the EF7 team.  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Comment: done: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

I have modified the Controller to return a Task:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CompanyController : Controller
{


    [HttpPut]
    public async Task UpdateAsync([FromBody] Company company)
    {
        if ((!ModelState.IsValid) || (company == null))
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await _repository.UpdateAsync(company);
        }
    }

}
```

+info: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2786